# How to use if condition in where section at postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
with specific_condition(a, b, c) as (
  values ('82757329', true, false)
)
(
select * 
from program as p, specific_condition as sc
where p.program_id = 1351235 case when sc.b = true then and p.program_type = 'movie' end);
```

I want to turn on/off an additional condition on where section like this.
If I set the specific_condition.b as "ture", I expect to see this result.

```
select * 
from program as p, specific_condition as sc
where p.program_id = 1351235 and p.program_type = 'movie';
```

And if I set it as "false", I need this output.

```
select * 
from program as p, specific_condition as sc
where p.program_id = 1351235
```

How to add and remove an additional option at where condition?

Answer (score 1):

You may repharse the where logic without using a `CASE` expression at all:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM program p
INNER JOIN specific_condition sc
    ON <join condition here>
WHERE p.program_id = 1351235 AND (!sc.b OR p.program_type = 'movie');
```

The `(...)` term in the `WHERE` clause evaulates to true if `sc.b` be false, or if it be true, and the program type is movie.